# Label tag or table tag?

Tags: html, css

I need to create the template layout for the form with the input.
Should I use label tag or table tag? Which one would give the best output?
Please suggest.

Comment: Your question is too short on detail for anyone to give you a really good answer, but in general, for the kind of thing you're asking the answer is always this: Use labels. Do not use tables. Using tables for this kind of layout is a technique that has been obsolete now for a very long time.

Answer (score 3):

They have nothing in common in your case.

Labels are used to "label" inputs with their explanation, like:

```
<div>
    <label>Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" />
</div>
```

Tables are used to tabularize data.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Header 1</td>
            <td>Header 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

### This approach is obsolete and NOT RECOMMENDED.

You can always use both if you wish, but there's better ways to position elements in a page.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Username Input</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Username:</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Not to mention that there are NEVER any reason to use a `<table>` to format a `<form>` - that's just semantically wrong in so many ways.

Comment: That's why I said there's always a better way to position elements in a page, not by using a table. Technically speaking though, you can still do it.

Comment: You CAN - you can also design the entire page using `<p>`-tags, or `<table>` - that doesn't make it any more correct. Just because you CAN, doesn't mean you SHOULD :)

Comment: I never said you're wrong, you're absolutely right you SHOULD NOT use such approach!! @junkfoodjunkie I've updated the answer so it's more evident :)